# How to switch views with buttons without storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, view

Does anyone know, how to switch views with buttons without storyboard?
Thanks for help !(:

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290592/how-to-change-view-on-button-click-in-iphone-without-navigation-controller

Answer (score 0):

```
 [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then implement your selector, buttonClicked

```
-(void) buttonClicked {
    UIView* newView = [[UIView alloc]init] ;
    self.view = newView ;
   }
```